# Interactable Combobox C#

Tags: c#, button, combobox, clickable

I have a few comboboxes in C# Visual Studio and I was wondering how I would make its dropdown menu items clickable, or to read which one is selected then do a strip of code. I was thinking of making something like invisible buttons, but the simple code I have done doesn't work and may be modified..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    { 
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        button1.Hide();
        if (comboBox1 = 1);
        button1.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to remove that semicolon after the `if` statement and add brackets.  `if (comboBox1 = 1){button1.Show();}`

Comment: @ECHELON You don't think `comboBox1 = 1` might not be a problem?

Comment: @LarsTech Forgive me. `if (comboBox.SelectedIndex  == 1){button1.Show();}`

Comment: Thanks @ECHELON for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a SelectionIndexChanged event to your ComboBox:

```
this.ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

The event fires at each change of your ComboBox. Your handler could do the actions you want:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    //your action
  }
  //....
}
```

You can also use the ComboBox.SelectedItem if you dont want to use the index.

Good luck!